# Radiobutton in a RadioGroup not visible after target API 22

Tags: java, android, radio-button

I was using a RadioGroup with RadioButtons it worked when my targed SDK was Android 4.4.2.
When I targeted the Android 5.01 it only works in Android 5.01.
In Android 4.4.2 it worked before but now when a radiobutton is checked it is not visible. The actions still works but the radiobutton is not checked or unchecked. And now it doesn't work in any of them.

Below is my radiobuttons. My background color is black.

```
    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radio_easy"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/easy"
        style="@style/RadioButtonText" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radio_medium"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/medium" 
        style="@style/RadioButtonText"/>

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radio_hard"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hard"
        style="@style/RadioButtonText" />

</RadioGroup>
```

Here is my AppTheme:

```
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <!--
        Theme customizations available in newer API levels can go in
        res/values-vXX/styles.xml, while customizations related to
        backward-compatibility can go here.
    -->
</style>

<!-- Application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
    <!-- All customizations that are NOT specific to a particular API-level can go here. -->
</style>
```

Comment: You may wish to consider posting your layout file, along with anything else of relevance (custom styles used by that layout, Java code, etc.). Also, please clarify what "targed SDK was 19" and "targeted the API 22" mean.

Answer (score 0):

You can use custom design for radioButton.

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item android:drawable="@drawable/check_red" android:state_checked="true" android:state_window_focused="false"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/check_gray" android:state_checked="false" android:state_window_focused="false"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/check_red" android:state_checked="true" android:state_pressed="true"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/check_gray" android:state_checked="false" android:state_pressed="true"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/check_red" android:state_checked="true" android:state_focused="true"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/check_gray" android:state_checked="false" android:state_focused="true"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/check_gray" android:state_checked="false"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/check_red" android:state_checked="true"/>
```

> I do not know if you still